# call jQuery function from code behind at master page on page load

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am calling a jQuery function from code behind in my master page on page load, and it is returning this error:

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Code Behind:-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    string script = "$(document).ready(function () {alert('hello'); });";
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "load", script, true);
}
```

I also tried this jquery function :-

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "ShowProgressBar", "ShowProgressBar();", true);
```

but then getting the error "ShowProgressBar is not defined".

Comment: Are you loaded the `jQuery` before your script?

Comment: check whether you have added reference to your jquery libarary

Comment: i have loaded my jquery after form, should I load these on head

Comment: Is there any way I can give reference of jquery cdn from code behind?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "Function1", "yourFunction();", true);
```

Comment: Is it any different from what the OP has already done: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "ShowProgressBar", "ShowProgressBar();", true);

Answer (score 0):

You miss to load your jquery file add following script tag in header.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
```